# 80s (?) short film about video tape that can wrap you up and is nefarious

Tags: story-identification, short-film

This was like a short film, not more than 20 minutes long I think.

A guy goes into a house, (I forget the motivation for this) and realizes he's in trouble.

Tape from video cassettes starts stalking him, after unwinding (don't remember if we see that specifically).  There's one scene where the "*bad tape*" is locked out of a room by the guy but goes under the carpet to get in (being flat and all).

I think the final scene is the guy getting all wrapped up completely with various additional video cassette tape that joins in the stalking.

It was an odd short film, I remember seeing it a long time ago as a kid, probably in the mid 80s, maybe on HBO.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

This is [Recorded Live](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0466572/), a short film made by S.S. Wilson in 1975.

It was apparently included as a video extra for the Tremors 4 DVD.

You might wish to note that the film has (recently) spawned a reboot.

Comment: Aw man... I just found it. :-P https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=S-Qeee8D2Ro

Comment: Nice job. I think it was the original one. I remember the video quality being better though.

Comment: Professor Jirafales got into some weird stuff here :P